# macOS asks for partition at every boot

Tags: boot, mac

Every time I reboot or switch on my Mac it asks me to select a boot partition.

I've already selected one in 'Preferences-> Boot Disk' but every time I boot I have to click "Machintosh HD":

[image]

Comment: Try Holding Ctrl [not Cmd] as you click the correct partition. Arrow will change to a circle & that should set default.

Comment: Hi Tetsuiin, circle appears then i click on it but after reboot: same problem. What can i do?

Comment: Run repairs from Recovery & see if that makes any difference. It would be good to know the prcise Mac & macOS too. Also, be certain you are doing this from an admin account.

Comment: Macbook pro 13 mid 2012, Catalina 10.15.6 but i have the same issue on another mac with 10.8. Repair didn't help (nothing to be repaired). Os works great after selecting MACOS partition.

Comment: The chances of this being a system issue stretching over 8 years are pretty much zero. It also eliminates Secure Boot issues. tbh, I'm about out of ideas for anything that could affect two Macs on vastly different OSes in the same way.

Comment: Thankyou btw, hope someone can help!